# VirtualBox Windows 10 with Ubuntu guest is too slow without 3d Acceleration

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have been using virtualbox in windows 10 with ubuntu guest for a while, the virtual machine options had enabled '3d acceleration' and everything was working fine. Nevertheless the screenshots that I took in ubuntu were completely dark and useless.

Googling the issue I found that disabling 3d acceleration and enabling shared clipboard would fix the dark screenshots. And in fact the screenshots were visible after making the changes.

The issue now is that the ubuntu is considerably slower than before when 3d acceleration was enabled.

Is there a workaround?